# stimulsoft cant update variable automically for using in code

Tags: stimulsoft

I add variable to stimulsoft with text component and use {} to change this test to variable
but when use it in code, i have error that this variable doesnt exists,
can anyone help me for this issue
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must write variable explicitly in variable panel
I have a this issue and after search,i find stimul doesn't update variable automatically
post your comment for me